# Revert to default completion mode

Tags: vim

Using the default vimrc (from `$VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim`), `CTRL-N` and `CTRL-P`, by default, appear to search my open buffers for completion options.

Which works great for me.

Occasionally, I switch completion modes (using `CTRL-X CTRL-F`, for example, to start doing filename completion), but I'm flummoxed as to how to switch back to the default.  None of the proffered options (like `CTRL-X CTRL-N` for keyword local completion) seem to work quite the same way.

So how can I revert back to checking my open buffers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From `:h ins-completion`:

> You enter CTRL-X mode by typing CTRL-X and one of the CTRL-X commands. You exit CTRL-X mode by typing a key that is not a valid CTRL-X mode command. Valid keys are the CTRL-X command itself, CTRL-N (next), and CTRL-P (previous).

So, basically, you must exit `CTRL-X` mode to be able to switch to generic completion. This can be done with `<C-e>` which is the default key for escaping completion, or any other `<C-something>` that is not already used in that context: `<C-ABCGHJMPQRSWZ>`.

Answer (score 5):

From the [documentation of vim](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ins-completion):

> Completion can be done for:
>
> ```
> 1. Whole lines                                     |i CTRL-X CTRL-L|
> 2. keywords in the current file                    |i CTRL-X CTRL-N|
> 3. keywords in 'dictionary'                        |i CTRL-X CTRL-K|
> 4. keywords in 'thesaurus', thesaurus-style        |i CTRL-X CTRL-T|
> 5. keywords in the current and included files      |i CTRL-X CTRL-I|
> 6. tags                                            |i CTRL-X CTRL-]|
> 7. file names                                      |i CTRL-X CTRL-F|
> 8. definitions or macros                           |i CTRL-X CTRL-D|
> 9. Vim command-line                                |i CTRL-X CTRL-V|
> 10. User defined completion                        |i CTRL-X CTRL-U|
> 11. omni completion                                |i CTRL-X CTRL-O|
> 12. Spelling suggestions                           |i CTRL-X s|
> 13. keywords in 'complete'                         |i CTRL-N|
> ```

and then it says (emphasis mine):

> ... You enter CTRL-X mode by typing CTRL-X and one of the
>   CTRL-X commands.  **You exit CTRL-X mode by typing a key that is not a valid
>   CTRL-X mode command.**  Valid keys are the CTRL-X command itself, CTRL-N (next),
>   and CTRL-P (previous).

Comment: Note: I have never tried CTRL-X, so please try this and let me know if it works. Also, it's unclear to me if other combinations such `CTRL-L`, `CTRL-K` etc are also considered "valid keys" or just the three mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

I have run into this issue multiple times. In WSL, I cannot just kill the terminal and the above upvoted suggestion did not work for me. It is likely I did C-x and in panic (as a reflex) I did C-s.

The solution was **C-q**

*Explanation*: In a console C-s is scroll lock. To resume: C-q. That got me back to the previous vi mode